# Stealing with your eyes,

Tags: halacha

Can someone please point me in the right direction where I can find Rashi on stealing with your eyes.

I am aware of a PDF online that talks about it, though I recall a class, where the teacher quoted Rashi on how the evil eye works and how it's a form of stealing and causing damage to the item, and the underlying question was, should you be liable, I think it was a machloket on this.

If i'm wrong on Rashi, and it was another individual please feel free to correct me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean בבא בתרא ב עמוד ב, regarding היזק ראיה?

Comment: @Avrah
Unfortunately no.

Comment: Just to clarify: Causing damage is not the same as stealing.

Comment: @N.T. That would be incorrect, why? Because stealing with you eyes, means that you're taking the energy from the item, leaving it without the energy it needs, making it susceptible to damages, and in some cases (With people) can be a direct hit where taking (stealing) the persons energy, will be exactly that. Imagine if you have a certain energy,  protecting you from harm, and someones gazes removes it from you, what then?

Comment: @N.T.     Also, Imagine your health is okay, you then invite someone or you go to work... and they give you a gaze of (Ayin Hara), the following day you're sick, how's this possible? Simply put it, the Eye, stole the bit of defense you had for your health, and now you have no energy, to prevent or fight off the sickness. I recall reading from the chafets chaim, that one should use amulets against the evil eye, Why? Because your very life depends on it.  Not believing in it, is a misconception of the past, because the fallen tree made a sound even if there was no one around to hear it. Physics.

Comment: That's not how ayin hara works. It creates damage, it does not remove something. See here for a similar concept: https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Leviticus.18.19.1?lang=he

Answer (score 3):

The Talmud says:

> Damage caused by looking is also damage.  [Bava Batra 2b]

> It is prohibited for a person to stand in someone else’s field and look at his crop while the grain is standing, because he casts an evil eye upon it and thereby causes him damage. [Bava Batra 2b]

This implies that you can harm by mere thought.  Coveting is damaging even if no action results from it.  The restriction assumes that people are certain to cast the evil eye by just looking.